# How to solve dependency issues after a `flutter upgrade`?

Tags: yaml, flutter-dependencies, pubspec, flutter-pubspec

I struggled to fix all the dependencies issues I had after the upgrade.

there is still one regarding

```
$ flutter pub get

Resolving dependencies...
Because no versions of i18n_extension match >9.0.2 <10.0.0 and i18n_extension 9.0.2 depends on sprintf ^7.0.0, i18n_extension ^9.0.2 requires sprintf ^7.0.0.
And because optimized_cached_image >=3.0.0 depends on sprintf ^6.0.0, i18n_extension ^9.0.2 is incompatible with optimized_cached_image >=3.0.0.
So, because shokaze depends on both i18n_extension ^9.0.2 and optimized_cached_image ^3.0.0, version solving failed.
exit code 1
```

And here is the yaml (I removed all the unnecessary lines for convenience):

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  intl: ^0.18.0 #^0.17.0
  i18n_extension: ^9.0.2 #^5.0.1
  optimized_cached_image: ^3.0.0 #^3.0.1
```

I don't explicitly ask for `sprintf`.

How could I solve the dependency issues?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a common problem in Flutter, and it's happening because the packages `i18n_extension` and `optimized_cached_image` depend on different versions of the `sprintf` package. Specifically, `i18n_extension` depends on version `^7.0.0` of `sprintf`, while `optimized_cached_image` depends on version `^6.0.0`. This causes a conflict because the two packages require different versions of the same dependency.

Here's a few ways to resolve this issue:

1. **Upgrade or downgrade one of the packages** - Check the pub.dev listings for `i18n_extension` and `optimized_cached_image` to see if there's a newer version of either package that resolves the dependency conflict. If a newer version isn't available, you might consider downgrading one of the packages if it's compatible with your project.
2. **Override the dependency** - You can override the `sprintf` version in your `pubspec.yaml` file to use a specific version. **This should only be done as a last resort, because it can lead to unexpected behavior if the overridden version isn't compatible with all packages that depend on it**. Here's an example of how to do this:

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  sprintf: ^7.0.0
```

3. Ask the package maintainers - If neither of the above options work, you can open an issue on the GitHub page for one of the packages (whichever one you think should update their `sprintf` dependency) and ask the maintainers to update the package to use a version of `sprintf` that's compatible with the other package.

Remember to run `flutter pub get` after making changes to your `pubspec.yaml` file to update your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You can vendor some of packages using the outdated dependencies using package [Vendor](https://pub.dev/packages/vendor). Here's [a step-by-step article](https://onepub.dev/Blog?id=yuuhnoflyg) on how to vendor a package and publish it on pub.

Another [helpful article](https://onepub.dev/Blog?id=zhhnoflygz) about resolving dependency-hell (DLL) error in your code.